# PHP HTML button not executing code when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm currently developing a page for a website which will return the values of flagged posts made by a user to display on screen. the user will then be able to delete the post which has been flagged when they click a button on screen. currently, I have a "delete" button which is displayed only when a post in the db has been flagged, however, i now want to be able to add functionality to the button so as I can then delete the post. i've been trying to implement the code to echo a javascript message when the button is clicked however the code isnt executed

code below:

```
$getUsername = "SELECT username FROM users JOIN user_post ON users.id = user_post.user_id WHERE user_id =$flaggedUserId";
                $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$getUsername);
                $resultthree = $con->query($getUsername);
                if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0)
                {
                    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                    echo nl2br ("\n <b>" . "Username: " . "</b>" . $rowthree['username']);

                    ?>
                    <br>
                    <input name="delete_flagged" type="button" id="delete_flagged_btn" value="Delete"/><br>


                    <?php

                if (isset($_POST['delete_flagged'])) 
                    {
                        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("delete") </script>';

                    }


                }
```

any help would be appreciate in trying to resolve this issue, it is my first time using php and html together!

Comment: Put your all php code like this `If(isset($_POST['button_name']){ // your code }` and check if it works. Is `delete_flagged` a button name which you are clicking?

Comment: isn't that what i have already been doing? i'm not sure i can see a difference in that and what i have done. yes delete_flagged is the name of a button as shown in the code "                    <input name="delete_flagged" type="button" id="delete_flagged_btn" value="Delete"/><br>
"

Comment: Yeah I saw that after comment :D sorry for that. You have given the name and put it properly in if condition so it should work. Let's do one thing comment your other php code and put this condition on top and run the code.

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't run the code when i do this

Comment: Hey I tried same thing here: http://shahroznawaz.com/test.php and it's working this is php code `if(isset($_POST['singlebutton'])){
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('delete');</script>";
}` I think your quotes are misplaced in `<script>`